# Typescript Angular2 errors when returning a promise and creating an observable from it

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am attempting to retrieve a token from ionics `storage` in `getToken()`and than use it in `refreshToken()` to see if the token is expired by passing it to `(this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token)` which returns a true or false depending on if the token is expired or not. I have put comments in `refreshToken()` where I am getting the following errors

Error 1:

`Error: TS2345:Argument of type '(response: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => void'.
Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
Property 'body' is missing in type 'Response'.`

Error 2:

`Error:(34, 46) TS2339:Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'.`

My code

```
import {AuthHttp, JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired} from "angular2-jwt";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {AuthService} from "../Services/Auth/auth.service";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import {AlertController} from "ionic-angular";

@Injectable()
export class TokenProvider {

jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
token;

constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp, private storage: Storage, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
}

getToken(): Promise<any> {
  return this.storage.get('token').then(token => {
     this.token = token;
  });
}

refreshToken(): Observable<any> {

  return this.token = Observable.fromPromise(this.getToken())
    .flatMap(() => {
      if(this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token))
      {
        return this.authHttp.get('localhost.api/refresh')
          .subscribe(   // ERROR 1 HERE
            (response: Response) => {
              this.token = response.json().token;  // ERROR 2 HERE
            },
            (error: Response) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add the import statements you have for this file?

Comment: Updated with imports

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not importing `Response` in your code. The compiler probably got confused on which `Response` to use as there may be multiple definitions in your typings :

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
```

Also, you are not returning the observable inside `flatMap`. You are returning the `Subscription`. Return the original observable like this:

```
refreshToken(): Observable <any> {

    let observable = Observable.fromPromise(this.getToken())
     .filter(() => this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token))
     .flatMap(() =>  this.authHttp.get('localhost.api/refresh'));
    observable.subscribe((response: Response) => {
            this.token = response.json().token;
        }, (error: Response) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    return observable;
}
```

Comment: That took away the response error (error 2) but now I get an error on the line `.flatMap(() => {` saying `Error:(28, 16) TS2345:Argument of type '() => Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'Subscription'.`

Comment: You have to return the observable inside `flatMap`. See my updated answer.

Comment: The errors are gone but when I run it in my browser now I get this error `TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Comment: You probably need a `filter` to filter out false conditions before `flatMap`

Comment: another error `Error:(81, 10) TS2339:Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'boolean'.` `this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired` returns true or false

Comment: There was a missing brace.

Answer (score 0):

The refreshToken function is incorrect

- You must not subscribe inside operators in RxJS
- Get returns an Observable (or promise as it seems in your case)

Try the following:

```
refreshToken(): Observable<any> {    
  return this.token = Observable.fromPromise(this.getToken())
    .flatMap(() => {
      if(this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token))
      {
        return this.authHttp.get('localhost.api/refresh')
      }
    })
    .catch(() => console.log(error))
    .map(response: Response => response.json())
    .subscribe(value => {
      this.token = value.token
    })
}
```